# Running time of merge sort :: All elements are identical

Tags: sorting, runtime, time-complexity, mergesort

Suppose we have an array of size n with all the elements identical. What will be O(n)? Will it be linear?

Comment: Mitch - No, its not given that all elements are identical. Eventually they are. What should be O(n) in that case?

Comment: Did you mean to send that comment somewhere else? It doesn't look as if anyone called Mitch has commented here.

Comment: Your comments about "O(n)" suggest that you may be confused about what that notation means, by the way. It sounds as if you think it means something like "the running time of the algorithm", but it doesn't. "O(n)" is one of many possible answers to the question "What is the running time of this algorithm?"; it means "at most some constant times *n*".

Comment: Gareth - Someone named Mitch commented that it should be O(1) if we know prior that all elements are identical. but that comment has been deleted.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, sounds like s/he was confused. So, anyway, what do you think the running time will be, and why?

Comment: I think it should be linear since there no necessity of merging once they are divided and compared.

Comment: Have you tried working through the algorithm in your head or on paper, to see whether that's actually so? (Maybe it is; or maybe expecting not to take any time merging is like Mitch's expectation that nothing at all would need doing. The only way to tell is to look at the actual algorithm and see whether there's anything in it to take advantage of this special situation.)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the algorithm is implemented.

With a standard "vanilla" implementation of mergesort, the time required to sort an array will always be Θ(n log n) because the merges required at each step each take linear time.

However, with the appropriate optimizations, it's possible to get this to run in time O(n). In many mergesort implementations, the input array is continuously modified so that larger and larger ranges are sorted, and when a merge step occurs, the algorithm uses an external buffer to merge two adjacent sorted ranges. In that case, there's a nifty optimization you can do: before doing the merge, check if the last element of the first range is less than or equal to the first element of the second range. If so, the two ranges taken together are already sorted, so no merging needs to be done.

Suppose you perform this optimization and try sorting an array where all elements are already sorted. What happens? Well, each call to mergesort will fire off two more recursive calls. After those return, it can check the endpoints of the sorted ranges and will notice that they're already in sorted order, so there's no more work left to be done. Overall, this does O(1) work per call, so we have this recurrence relation for the time complexity of the algorithm:

> T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1)

This solves to O(n), so only linear work is done.